# Registering an application to a URI Scheme

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, registry

I have a wpf app I have registered as a URI Scheme by doing the following.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
-->myappname
   -->shell
      -->open
         -->command
            (Default) = "c:\pathtomyapp\app.exe"
```

Fantastic! However, my application enforces that only one instance can run at a time. How can I detect that my app is already running and for example bring it to the foreground?

Comment: Please kindly show how the app.exe you execute via URI Scheme?

Comment: Please consider revising the title of this question.  It's more to do with single instances rather than URI scheme handlers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a named mutex to detect that application is already running. Or, if you have a GUI app, you can inherit your form from [VisualBasic's SingleInstance application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3xx6ewx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) , and it will do routhgly the same for you.

```
  public class SingleInstanceController
    : WindowsFormsApplicationBase
  {
    public SingleInstanceController()
    {
      // Set whether the application is single instance
      this.IsSingleInstance = true;

      this.StartupNextInstance += new
        StartupNextInstanceEventHandler(this_StartupNextInstance);
    }

    void this_StartupNextInstance(object sender, StartupNextInstanceEventArgs e)
    {
      // Here you get the control when any other instance is
      // invoked apart from the first one.
      // You have args here in e.CommandLine.

      // You custom code which should be run on other instances
    }

    protected override void OnCreateMainForm()
    {
      // Instantiate your main application form
      this.MainForm = new Form1();
    }
  }

[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{    
  SingleInstanceController controller = new SingleInstanceController();
  controller.Run(args);
}
```

It does not matter whenever you write your code in C#, as this class is avaliable as a part of .Net framework and for all languages.

And here is a [wrapper for the WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47958/WPF-Application-Wrapper-with-Single-Instance-Suppo)

Comment: This stuff seems to be tied to `WindowsForms`.  Is this proper to use in a WPF app?

Comment: Added wpf wrapper link to the answer.

Comment: This is almost perfect. Unfortunately the WPF wrapper errors when using .NET 4.0

Comment: Looks like the MissingAssembly error handler is forcing a lookup for a non existent dll and then erroring. Comment it out and it works but launching a second instance of the app just throws more errors. :(